# BackgroundWorker и ID потока

Tags: c#, многопоточность

В своей программе использую BackgroundWorker для того чтобы некоторые операции выполнять в фоне. Однако всплыл некий момент:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += delegate (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) { };
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate (object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
};
Console.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

выводит разные ID потока. Я полагал, что `BackgroundWorker` и сделан для того, чтобы результат выполнения передавался в основной поток. Я не прав?

Из [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ck8bc5c6.aspx):

Методы, обрабатывающие **события `ProgressChanged` и `RunWorkerCompleted`** имеют доступ к пользовательскому интерфейсу приложения, так как эти события **вызываются в потоке, который вызвал метод `RunWorkerAsync`**.  Однако обработчик событий `DoWork` не может работать с объектами пользовательского интерфейса, поскольку он запускается в фоновом потоке.

UPD:

```
  System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker worker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
  worker.DoWork += delegate (object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e) 
  {
    Console.WriteLine("DoWork: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    (sender as System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(50, null);
  };
  worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate (object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("RunWorkerCompleted: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
  };
  worker.ProgressChanged += delegate (object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("ProgressChanged: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
  };
  Console.WriteLine("MainProcess: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
  worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
  worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

выдаёт:

> MainProcess: 9
>
> DoWork: 12
>
> ProgressChanged: 6
>
> RunWorkerCompleted: 12

Comment: Вы все это делаете в консольном приложении? Или в winforms?

Comment: Wpf. А какая разница?

Comment: В гуевом приложении будет отрабатывать как и положено, а такие результаты, как я понимаю, получены в консольном? Тут дело в контексте (ох, надо вспоминать...)

Comment: WPF это гуи, а не консоль

Comment: а как именно вы его под WPF запускаете? где именно код вписан?

Comment: в Main() перед app.run();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BackgroundWorker вызывает `ProgressChanged` и `RunWorkerCompleted` через `SynchronizationContext`. При этом используется `SynchronizationContext.Current` на момент вызова `RunWorkerAsync`.

Т.е. если вы вызвали `RunWorkerAsync` из потока, связанного с UI - например, повесили код из вопроса на синхронный `ButtonClick` - основной кейс, под который разрабатывался `BackgroundWorker`

```
private void button_Click(object sender1, RoutedEventArgs ee)
{
    System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker worker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
    // ... snip
    Console.WriteLine("MainProcess: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

то будет захвачен контекст, связанный с UI-потоком:

```
MainProcess: 9
DoWork: 13
ProgressChanged: 9
RunWorkerCompleted: 9
```

А если вы свой код запустили в потоке, в котором уже нет `SynchronizationContext.Current` - то перенаправление событий не сработает - т.к. их некуда перенаправлять:

```
private void button_Click(object sender1, RoutedEventArgs ee)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) => StartWorker());
}

private static void StartWorker()
{
    System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker worker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
    // ... snip
    Console.WriteLine("MainProcess: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

И события просто отработают в потоках, взятых из пула, чтобы не прерывать DoWork()

Результат:

```
MainProcess: 12
DoWork: 13
ProgressChanged: 14
RunWorkerCompleted: 14
```

Comment: Все заработало, запихал в делегат `app.Startup`. Спасибо за ответ!